# pg-promise connection to heroku postgres

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, pg-promise

so, I did everything the docs said, and it works well with prisma. but I tried connecting my pg-promise code using the database url provided by the heroku-pg (its a free account)

```
try {
    const cn = {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        max: 20,
    };
    var db = pgp(cn);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

there seems to be a problem cause this error occurs

error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "197.156.77.76", user "*********", database "******", SSL off

Comment: It is a server configuration issue, and not one related to `pg-promise`.

Comment: Hey so thank you, I figured it out. u need to make it like so... ```const cn = {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        max: 20,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        },
    };
    var db = pgp(cn);``` check this page out https://www.javaniceday.com/post/pg-promise-self-signed-certificate-error-in-postgres